# Cannot implement interface, which contains interface

Tags: c#, interface

i have a problem.
I have code:
`

```
   public interface IUpgradeable
    {
    IUpgrade UpgradeEntity{ get; }
    }

public interface ISomeUpgrade : IUpgrade 
{
 // ...
}

public interface IUpgrade 
{
 // ...
}

public class SomeClass : IUpgradeable
{
 public ISomeUpgrade SomeUpgrade { // ...} 
}
`
```

Why i cannot use that ? I need that for more interfaces which implemement IUpgrade ...

Comment: If you have a specific error, please post it.

Comment: you can not use what? its unclear what is the problem. please clarify.

Comment: I cannot use ISomeUpgrade over IUpgrade, even ISomeUpgrade implement IUpgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class must implement the interface strictly, you cannot change the return type neither the Property name.

If I understand correctly, what you really want is a class that implements `IUpgradable` with different `IUpgrade` per class. This can be obtained using generics:

```
public interface IUpgradeable<TUpgrade> where TUpgrade : IUpgrade
{
    TUpgrade UpgradeEntity{ get; }
}

public interface ISomeUpgrade : IUpgrade 
{
 // ...
}

public interface IUpgrade 
{
 // ...
}

public class SomeClass : IUpgradeable<ISomeUpgrade>
{
    public ISomeUpgrade UpgradeEntity{ get; } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you man. Name was just typo in question there, but at type i failed. Generics if best choice for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeClass` does not implement `IUpgradeable.UpgradeEntity.get`

you specified a property with different name, and different return type...

what you could do is

```
public class SomeClass : IUpgradeable
{
    public IUpgrade UpgradeEntity { get { ... return new CSomeUpgrade(); } } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. The name was just typo.
And thats problem, i return "child" of IUpgrade. Its not okey ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement UpgradeEntity explicitly like this:

```
public interface IUpgradeable
{
    IUpgrade UpgradeEntity { get; }
}

public interface ISomeUpgrade : IUpgrade
{
    // ...
}

public interface IUpgrade
{
    // ...
}

public class SomeClass : IUpgradeable
{
    IUpgrade IUpgradeable.UpgradeEntity => SomeUpgrade;
    public ISomeUpgrade SomeUpgrade { get; }
}
```